# Reading binary file data from MATLAB using fread()

Tags: matlab, dataset, fread

I am trying to use the offline data set located at:
http://www.nlpr.ia.ac.cn/databases/handwriting/Offline_database.html .

However, I have trouble processing the data (the CASIA-HWDB1.0-1.2  gnt files).
I used the sample code located at http://www.nlpr.ia.ac.cn/databases/Download/GntRead.cpp.pdf but this does not compile. As a result, I am using MATLAB to read the data, but the data does not appear to be read correctly as the images displayed are not reasonable. My test code is below which is supposed to read and display one image:

```
fid = fopen("HWDB1.1trn_gnt.alz", 'rb', 'n','GB2312');
length= fread(fid, 1, 'uint32');
label= fread(fid, 2, 'int8');
width= fread(fid, 1, 'uint16');
height= fread(fid, 1, 'uint16');
bitmap=fread(fid, width*height, 'uint8');
imgtmp=reshape(bitmap, [height, width]);
imagesc(imgtmp)
fclose(fid)
```

Obviously this does not work since my width is 0, and that can't be so for a picture! And imagesc gives a picture of noise.

thanks

Comment: Did you look at `label`? Does it have the expected values?

Comment: You should also reshape as `[width,height]`, and then transpose. The data seems to be stored row-wise, but MATLAB stores it column-wise.

Comment: It does not have the expected values (the GB 2312 Character Map). Just to be sure, the line fread(fid, 1, 'uint32') says to read 4 bytes of data and interpret it as a single number of the unit32 data type, correct? If that is the case, what is the interpretation of fread(fid, n, 'uint32') for arbitrary n?  The documentation I see does not seem sufficiently clear.

Comment: As a checksum, you could check that `length` is equal to `(widthxheight)+10`. Also the document does not specify the endianess of the data, so if it doesn't work in one way (likely little endian by default from your machine), try to read the value larger than 1 byte as big endian and see if the values make more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question might be dumb but are you sure that the file you're reading is the right one ? Because from what I read, .alz files are archives files such as .zip (moreoever I couldn't find your file on the link you provided).

And when you use `fread(fid,n,'uint32')` matlab reads a line vector with  `uint32` format and n el

Comment: You're right. The datasets where I got the files did not mentioned anything about needing to decompress them (even after I unzipped them). Thanks